# SQLAlchemy автозаполнение таблицы на основе другой таблицы

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, таблицы

Есть две таблицы: `USERS` и `FREE_TIME`. При добавлении в таблицу `USERS` строки `name=example, date=10.01.2021, time=15:00` как реализовать функционал моделей таблицы, чтобы в таблицу `FREE_TIME` автоматически записывались значения `date=10.01.2021` и по условиям времени для колонок (09:00-11:00 и 13:00-18:00) в определенную колонку записывалось значение `True`?

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String),
    date = db.Column(db.String),
    time = db.Column(db.String)

class Free_time(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'free_time'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.String)
    time_1 = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    time_2 = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```